# "Make sure it work" or "make sure it works"?

Tags: grammar

Is it to "make it work", "make sure it work", or is it to "make it works", "make sure it works"?

I was thinking the ones without s are correct, but Google results show an overwhelming favor for those with the s, so I need some answers.

Comment: ***Wrong forum***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. **Make it work** (correct)
> 2. **Make sure it work** (incorrect)
> 3. **Make it works** (incorrect)
> 4. **Make sure it works** (correct)

No 2 should be: *make sure it works* (just as you would say, "Does it work?"  "Yes, it works!")

No 3 see first sentence.  This is a special construction — see below.

See meaning 15 in Merriam-Webster Dictionary, [to cause to act in a certain way:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make) compel, e.g. *make her give it back.*

Comment: @mari-lou-a, this is the first time I've had a post edited by someone else.  I can't remember what I wrote well enough to be able to tell what you changed!  Could you please explain in a comment, or tell me how to make a comparison?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I found it!  Never mind....  Thanks for re-formatting.